# Is there a way to get a Dockerfile to build the latest Word Press version and the latest PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, dockerfile

The supported tag list is here - https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress but I am looking for more information.

If I use this tag -

`FROM wordpress:apache`

It will load the latest version of Word Press and PHP 8.0.30. However I want it to load the latest version of PHP which I believe is 8.2

Is there a way to get it to build the latest Word Press and the latest PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Try using tag `wordpress:php8.2-apache` also there is a [new tag beta](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/tags?page=1&name=apache) for php8.2 with apache